# How to check if Cypress is using run mode or open mode

Tags: testing, browser, cypress, headless

Does Cypress have a variable I can grab to determine if it's running via `cypress open` or `cypress run`?

Comment: I am not sure whether cypress provides this or not, but you can check out the module API if that helps - https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api#cypress-run

Answer (score 13):

Yes it does:

```
if(Cypress.config('isInteractive')) {
   // cypress open
} else {
   // cypress run
}
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks!